# Difference between physical and virtual memory visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, virtual-memory

I am trying to write a custom memory manager and right now I am allocating a global array of bytes like:

```
char g_retail_memory[512*MB];
```

When i then look in the resource monitor of Windows 7 it reports that around 512 MBs of **virtual** memory has been allocated. can someone please explain why I am not getting **physical** memory? If i use malloc() instead i get physical memory. Am I doing something wrong? In that case, is there a correct way of obtaining physical memory under visual c++?

Comment: how are you determining that you are getting "physical memory" with malloc?

Comment: the same way I am determining not getting it ... :) via Windows resource manager but as I learned in the next post this information can be incorrect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

All physical memory you allocate will also be virtual memory, because VM is the way the system presents memory to applications in modern operating systems.  The reason you may not see some allocations appear as physical could be that the memory has never been used, so the OS didn't actually need to find physical memory for it, but will when/if the memory is first used.

Note that virtual memory's backing physical memory can later "go away" if the OS needs it for another application.  This is sometimes referred to as "swapping" or "paging."

Comment: Ah okay! I see. So what I am doing is correct for preallocating memory?

Comment: If it were me I would use malloc, just because asking for 512 MB in an array like that is a lot, and there's no way for the system to report a failure to allocate it other than to terminate your program.  Whereas with malloc you could at least detect that the large up-front allocation failed (with malloc returning NULL).

Comment: Okok... I am using Jason Gregory's Game Engine Architecture as a reference where he says that a global array of bytes allocates effectively out of the executables BBS segment. But I agree with you, it will be hard to detect errors...

Comment: That would be BSS, not BBS.  :)

Comment: :) i have now solved all problems by allocating memory with the win32 in case anyone is interested.